# aws-sdk javascript filter on tag:key=value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Folks,
  I am having difficult time understanding the docs `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html`

I need to grab all the running instances with the following tags assigned to them:

`project`=`foo`
`environment`=`production`

The following does not seem to work.

```
var params = {
    DryRun: false,
    Filters: [
        {
            Name: 'instance-state-name',
            Values: [
                'running'
            ],
        },
        {
            Name: 'tag:key=value',
            Values: [
                'foo',
                'production'
            ],
        },
    ]
};

ec2.describeInstances(params, function (err, data) {
...
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your tag's key is 'foo' and its value is 'production', you should change your code to the following.  The Name is in the 'tag:key' format, and the Values are the data you are looking for that correspond to that key.

```
{
    Name: 'tag:foo',
    Values: [
            'production'
    ],
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish the Node.js SDK documentation had this example. Filtering by tag is not obvious.